# Change the way AngularJS serializes Date

Tags: angularjs, json, date

I would like to serialize a javascript Date without UTC/'zulu' (the standard behaviour) when making an $http request. As default a `Date(2015,0,1,12,0,0)` will generate a `2015-1-1T15:00:00z` in a time zone -0300, but I would like to get '2015-1-1T12:00:00'.

One way is to change the `Date.prototype.toISOString` as it's used by JSON and that is used by AngularJS. Is there a better way that just change the date in a $http call like intercepting the `$httpProvider` in some way?

Comment: Is the end goal to render a string in a template such that you don't see the timezone info?

Answer (score 0):

## 1

You can configure $httpProvider (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations), but probably you should also set inverse transformation for response. It will work for ALL requests.

## 2

You can serialize data before passing it to $http service call using custom REPLACER function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).